# Android,Java - AutocompleteTextView list display under the edit box

Tags: java, android-studio

I have an AutocompleteTextView dropDown list displaying at the top of the page:
  [here the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGiYq.png)

Ho can I let the list display **aligned under the edit text box**?

Comment: Could you show xml file?

Comment: <AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/d_b"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
android:layout_below="@+id/start_box"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:background="@drawable/write_text"
android:clickable="true"
android:drawableLeft=" @mipmap/ic_search "
android:enabled="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:hint="@string/D2"
android:inputType="text"
android:singleLine="true"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android:dropDownAnchor="@id/yourIdOfViewOnTop"
android:dropDownHeight="100dp"